# How to say "at least" as in "at least help me!"

Tags: grammaire, traduction, expressions

How do you express "At least" as in the sentence "At least help me!" I think it's (literally) "au moins" but that sounds a bit strange.

Thanks!

Comment: c'est bien "au moins" que l'on dit, c'est très courant.

Comment: Also, you're asking a lot of questions that could be solved with the use of a dictionary. Try using [Reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/), which is the best I've found and has good translations for a wide breadth of words, phrases, and idioms. Don't just use FL&U to shortcut looking things up yourself. I have done this sometimes myself but I try to avoid it wherever possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say, simply,

> "Aidez-moi / Aide-moi, au moins !"